# Change color in svg file through command line (inkscape)

Tags: command-line, svg, inkscape

I have an .svg file with only one color. I want to change this color to another and export it through command line. (I have to do it about 100 times, so doing it by hand doesn't work.) I use Inkscape at the moment.
I am able to change the background color and export with this command:

```
inkscape -f name.svt -e output_name.png -b #000080
```

But I cannot find the way to change the normal color.
I find this verb:

```
org.inkscape.color.replacecolor
```

But I don't know, how to add the color I want to use, somewhere I read, that I cannot add variables to verbes, but in that case how can be this verb used?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11):

This is not a general purpose solution, but since a SVG file is just XML internally, if your SVG file is simple enough you might be able to get away with a simple `sed` replacement. For example the following replaces #000000 (black) with #ffffff (white):

```
sed -e "s/#000000/#ffffff/" input.svg >output.svg
```

This may or may not be good enough for your needs.

Comment: awesome trick. in case it's helpful to anyone, I'll add that this method works to convert svgs with multiple colors to monochrome. for instance `sed -e "s/#....../#000000/" input.svg > output.svg` to create an all black svg.

Comment: it won't work when there is no color set, like in every svg icon in the internet

Answer (score 0):

Although inkscape is a powerful tool, I think you will have more luck (control) with xlst tranformations. This will allow you to do anything to an xml file rather than parsing the file as an svg image and relying on the available API. You might take a look at a tool like xsltproc for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SVG file with no fill color set, you can for example use:

```
sed -e "s/<svg/<svg fill=\"#ff0000\"/" input.svg > output.svg
```

This example changes the fill color to red (#ff0000).